# Postgresql select item(book) if it has two or more values(tags) with many to many relations

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have tables:

1. books(id, ...)
2. tags_books(tag_id, book_id)

How can i find books that have two or more tags, let say tag_id (1,4,5)? And it should work with LIMIT/OFFSET.

My only idea is to filter if books_tags has any of tags, than agregate them in array and filter rows with array.length < 3 (total tags for current search). But i don't think it's a reasonable approach...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must join the tables and group by book. Then use the HAVING clause to put the condition:

```
select 
  b.id
from books b inner join tags_books t
on t.book_id = b.id
where tag_id in (1,4,5)
group by b.id
having count(distinct tag_id) = 3
```

If you don't need the books to have all 3 tags but any of them then remove the HAVING clause.
If you want at least 2 tags then change to:

```
having count(distinct tag_id) >= 2
```

Comment: Thanks, forgot to ask, what if i need to exclude some tags in the same query?

Comment: Like you want to select books that **don't** have the tags 1, 2, 3?

Comment: yep, i think AND tb.tag_id NOT IN (11,12,13) is ok?

Comment: Try this: `select 
  b.id
from books b inner join tags_books t
on t.book_id = b.id
group by b.id
having sum(case when t.tag_id in (1,2,3) then 1 else 0 end) = 0`

Comment: If you want to combine the queries do something like this: `select 
  b.id
from books b inner join tags_books t
on t.book_id = b.id
group by b.id
having 
sum(case when t.tag_id in (1,2,3) then 1 else 0 end) >= 2
and 
sum(case when t.tag_id in (11,12,13) then 1 else 0 end) = 0`

Comment: i'm just curious, will it be fast with many books and tags for many requests?

Comment: The query in my answer should be fast because there is a WHERE clause which limits the number of rows. For the last one in my comment you can include: `WHERE tag_id in (1,2,3,11,12,13)` if you see that it is slow. But anyway you have to test. You need conditional aggregation so it depends on the number of rows queried.